# Push-forward of quasi-coherent sheave on affine scheme is quasi-coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X=$ Spec$R$, $Y=$ Spec$S$, $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $M$ be a $R$-module, and let $\mathcal{F}=\tilde{M}$ be the sheaf on $X$ induced by $M$. How can I show that the pushforward of $\mathcal{F}$ by $f$, $f_* \mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf induced by $M_S$, where $M_S$ means $M$ considered as a $S$ module?

Here is my (feeble) attempt:
Let $U$ be any open set of $Y$. $f_* \mathcal{F}(U)=\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(U))=\{(\phi_p)_{p \in f^{-1}(U)}:\phi_p \in M_p $ and ...$\}$, meanwhile $\tilde{M_S}(U)=\{(\phi_q)_{q \in U}:\phi_q \in M_q $ and ...$\}$, ('...' contains some local conditions in the sheaf). Now the indexing $p \in f^{-1}(U)$ and $q \in U$ do not 'match up', by that I mean not all $q \in U$ is of form $f(p)$, where $p \in f^{-1}(U)$, so I do not see how one can construct a correspondence from $f_* \mathcal{F}(U)$ to $\tilde{M_S}(U)$. Also I do not recall any results relating the $M_p$ and $M_q$, hence I am having trouble seeing how the 2 sets can be considered equal.

I do believe I am missing something here, as a few algebraic geometry books I've flipped through state this as 'immediate from definitions'. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not convinced this is "immediate from definitions", but it isn't anything complicated. One thing to note is that it suffices to consider only the open subschemes $U \subseteq Y$ of the form $U = D (s)$ for some $s \in S$; then $f^{-1} U = D (r) \subseteq X$ where $r \in R$ is the image of $s$. Then you can use the fundamental fact about sections of quasicoherent sheaves over distinguished open subschemes.

Comment: I don't understand the fundamental fact you are referring to, say I have showed $f_* \mathcal{F} (D(s))=\tilde{M_S}(D(s))$ for every distinguished open subscheme $D(s)$, how can I piece them together and arrive at the same conclusion for arbitrary open set $U$?

Comment: That follows from the fact that the distinguished open subschemes form a basis for the topology.

Comment: Well yes, but how can I relate, say if $U=\cup_i D(s_i)$, $\tilde{M_S}(U)$ to $\tilde{M_S}(D(s_i))$? and a similar formula needs to hold for $f_* \mathcal{F}$ too, right?

Comment: Use the sheaf condition!

Comment: O nevermind, I understand this part now, but now I'm working on showing the 2 sheaves agree on the distinguished open sets...

Comment: I can't seem to obtain any simplification by considering distinguished open sets only, the only thing I have managed to construct is a map from $\tilde{M_S}{D(s)}$ to $f_* \mathcal{F}(D(s))$ given by $(\phi_q)_{s \not\in q} \mapsto (i_p(\phi_{f(p)}))_{r \notin p}$ where $i_p:M_{f(p)} \to M_p$ is the canonical map, but I can't see why this map would be bijective. Can I please ask for a further hint?

Comment: You really need to use the fundamental fact about quasicoherent sheaves I mentioned. See e.g. Proposition 5.1 in [Hartshorne, Ch. II].

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean after a good night's sleep, thanks so much! Do you mind if I type up an answer myself using your hints? just for reference for others

Comment: Please feel free.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution based on the hints of @Zhen Lin.

$$f_* \mathcal{F}(D(s))=\mathcal{F} (f^{-1}(D(s)))
=\mathcal{F}(D(f^*s))
=M_{f^*s}
=M_s
=\tilde{M(D(s))}$$

Hence the 2 sheaves agree on the distinguished open sets $D(s)$, as these sets form a basis of the topology, we can use the gluing property of sheaves to see that they agree on every open set also.